# Using Pfizer as a booster dose if someone was vaccinated with Sinopharm: what is good practice?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system

I am curious if there is established practice of using Pfizer as a booster dose if a person was vaccinated with Sinopharm.
One example I think is here which says it is possible
https://www.timeoutdubai.com/news/471688-covid-19-vaccine-booster-uae-everything-you-need-to-know

But I am curious about wider experience.

Comment: Combinations of boosters of different vaccines has not been tested; there's a combinatorial problem of studying all the different possible permutations. Even boosters more generally have only had limited study.

Comment: @BryanKrause  Have you (or john or anyone else) learned anything that could shed light on this question during the last four months?